# Why this jquery plugin not working with 1.4.2

Tags: jquery

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/semantictabs

What is the means of this
    Status - Recommended for 1.0.x

I'm using this plugin code as it is http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.semantictabs.js_4.txt

then this ( I'm also using prototype.js onsite)

```
jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#mytabset").semantictabs({
  panel:'.mypanelclass',            //-- Selector of individual panel body
  head:'headelement',             //-- Selector of element containing panel header, i.e. h3
  active:':first'                         //-- Which panel to activate by default
});
});
```

Comment: Try changing `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$("#mytabset").semantictabs({
  panel:'.mypanelclass', //-- Selector of individual panel body
  head:'headelement', //-- Selector of element containing panel header, i.e. h3
  active:':first' //-- Which panel to activate by default
});
```

to

```
jQuery("#mytabset").semantictabs({
  panel:'.mypanelclass', //-- Selector of individual panel body
  head:'headelement', //-- Selector of element containing panel header, i.e. h3
  active:':first' //-- Which panel to activate by default
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me, or it doesn't refer to the jQuery version at all, but to the version range of the plugin itself. The latest release is from January this year - I don't think anybody will develop a plugin for JQuery 1.0.x nowadays.

I'd just try it out. Chances are it works.

**Re your update:** You seem to be using it already. Is there something that doesn't work?

Comment: @Pekkaa - did you checked this?

Comment: @metal No. What doesn't work? What happens? Any error messages?